# IIS7 Application Pool crash when reading cookies

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, application-pool

This one is a real challenge:
I've set IIS7.5 on my computer and started to develop a website. Each night I'm backing it up on my web server, win 2008r2 sp1 (all updates). It works flawlessly.

Yet, I've encountered a huge problem when sharing cookies across application pools. www.example.com was set to 127.0.0.1 so I could test the website locally. It created cookies BUT when I removed the HOSTS record (to point back to web server) - the application pool on the web server crashed. It happens each and every time, and might have to do something with the sessionID cookie, since without cookies it DOESNT crash!

the log file is:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: nlssorting.dll, version: 4.0.30319.239, time stamp: 0x4e182039
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000001d7d
Faulting process id: 0x9f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccbbd76b7a443c
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
Report Id: a9cfd0cf-27ca-11e1-bced-00215e5304da
```

What is going on?

Comment: Have you seen this connect bug? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/665157/nlssorting-fault-crashes-iis

Comment: yes, no real info there but if it's a bug there's no chance it hasn't been fixed yet... I think (April '11)

Comment: I would file another or add to it, so they know it's a real issue.

Comment: The clue to the problem is in the Exception code: `0xc00000fd` - that's a stack overflow happening right there. The only way to begin troubleshooting this is to use DebugDiag or ADPlus to capture a crash dump of the pool. When you've done that you need to load up the dump in WinDbg + SOS and start analysing. You should take a look at Tess Ferrandez's debugging labs which will help you get started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx  .

Comment: Does the site work after the app pool recycles? Or does it repeatedly crash on every page you hit after you change the HOSTS setting to go to the server?

Comment: @S_S I am experiencing this exact problem and it is giving me an absolute nightmare. It also seems to be related to Session as it crashed every time somebody logs in. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET auth cookie gets encrypted and decrypted using the machineKey setting in web.config. If you don't have it there, it is auto-generated each time app starts. It's a good idea to set it to a fixed value to avoid cookie invalidation between app restarts.

I can't be sure, but it might be that asp.net session cookie is also dependent on this encryption key. I'm pretty sure viewstate is using it also (this would be why you see invalid-viewstate errors when you initiate a postback after the app was shut down due to inactivity).

So, try setting the machine key and see it that still happens. You can use IIS to generate one, and it'll insert it into the correct spot within the web.config.